# Microsoft bot older version warning message persistent even after update

Tags: node.js, botframework

I update the version of SDK to 3.8.1 and still getting warning messages on local bot emulator.

> Warning: The Bot is using an SDK version earlier than 3.5.0.
>   Warning: SDK versions earlier than 3.5.0 use an authentication
>   configuration that will no longer work after July 31, 2017.
>   Warning: For your bot to continue working beyond this date, please
>   update your bot to use an SDK version greater than or equal to 3.5.0.

```
Environment setup:
Lang   |  Nodejs
Editor |  Visual Studio Code
OS     |  macOS Sierra
          botframework-emulator v3.5.29
SDK    |  "botbuilder": "^3.8.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was tracked down and fixed with SDK v3.8.3 which was released earlier today. You can find the details on **[GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2775)**.

This bug stemmed from the 'User-Agent' header being accidentally removed.

Comment: i was following the same and used that solution only.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue with `botframework-emulator 3.5.29` and `botbuilder 3.7.1`.

Bot Emulator is checking the version by looking to *user-agent* header (code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/v3.5.29/src/server/controllers/connector/conversationsController.ts#L183) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/v3.5.29/src/server/versionManager.ts#L52)), and the header is set by the bot framework [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/botbuilder%403.7.0/Node/core/src/bots/ChatConnector.ts#L600).

I'd say that it is a problem in the emulator, as the header *IS* being sent by the bot framework. In my case I get:

`User-Agent: BF-DirectLine (Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1 +https://botframework.com/ua)`

when `POST`ing a message to `/api/messages`, but the emulator is expecting that header in requests made to `https://directline.botframework.com/v3/conversations/:conversationId/activities/:activityId`, causing the *user-agent* header to be undefined.

Comment: More detailed answer.